# SQL - Sum using select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I want to sum a values that came from selected statement. My query goes like:

```
 select sum((SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, ActualCompletionDate, ActualStartDate) AS DateDiff))
 from ProjectMilestone;
```

But this query give an error

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to use a subquery, aggregation with a single query is enough:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, ActualCompletionDate, ActualStartDate))
FROM
    ProjectMilestone PM;
```